# Access Database LIMIT keyword

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm trying to get my page listing function working in ASP with an Access database, but I don't know the alternative to LIMIT in Microsoft SQL. I have tried TOP but this doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the statement am using with MySQL:

```
SELECT  * FROM customers ORDER BY customerName DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

How can I convert this to work with Access Database?

Comment: question states MySql, tag says SQl Server

Comment: Many of the insular SQL Server people mistakenly read "sql" as referring to their personal platform only.

Comment: You might like to consider a different approach, such as GetRows : http://www.asp101.com/samples/viewasp.asp?file=db_getrows.asp

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to ms-access view:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM customers ORDER BY customerName;
```

will fetch an error "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word",

the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM customers ORDER BY customerName;
```

(note the brackets)..

Answer (score 4):

Top(5) is deceptive. Internally the database returns all records, then Access just shows the Top 5 rows. I'd use the LIMIT keyword instead of Top(n).

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent in access for LIMIT, but the TOP statement can be manipulated into working in a similar fashion to say, "... LIMIT BY 50, 250" etc,. I found out by experiment that if you wanted to get the "next 50" records at an offset of 250 you could try the following

SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 50 tab2.* FROM (SELECT TOP 300 tab1.* FROM my_table AS tab1 ORDER BY column_name ASC) AS tab2 ORDER BY column_name DESC) ORDER BY column_name ASC;

This should return the records from row 250 to 300, in ascending order (provided they exist.) with or without a unique index. A WHERE clause could tidy the results further if need be.

A little convoluted but I hope it helps.