# How to simulate the LIMIT MySQL clause with an Access database?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic, limit

In an ASP page (VBScript) that gets a recordset from a *.MDB Access database, how can I simulate the LIMIT clause of MySQL in the SQL?

```
<%
    Dim cn,rs
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
    cn.Open dbConnectionString
    Dim sql
    sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10,50"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Access, limiting results to the top X results look like this.

MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10
```

Access

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM mytable
```

If you would like to use an offset, like in your example, check this answer:

[MS Access LIMIT X, Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627032/ms-access-limit-x-y)

Comment: Does that offset method syntax work with SQL Server too?  If it does then I'm bookmarking that question

Comment: Here's a link for SQL Server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server/2135461#2135461