# How to select rows m through n in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am modifying a query for a sub-report in Access 2016 and need to select a set of rows, not all rows. By default the query generated looks like:

```
SELECT table_name.a, table_name.b, table_name.c
FROM table_name
WHERE (((table_name.dist_ft)<3001));
```

How can I select only rows *m* through *n* instead of all rows?

Thanks for your insights! ... [edit]

An additional clarification - when I run the query like

SELECT TOP 16 *
FROM table_name
WHERE (((table_name.dist_ft)<3001));

... or any other variation I've tried with TOP my sub-report does not get populated. It only contains data when all fields are selected and TOP is not used. I must be missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access LIMIT X, Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627032/ms-access-limit-x-y)  Simple two top nested queries (derived tables) with the needed order by.  or get top n where ID not in top m

Answer (score 0):

Is ID your "row number" here?

```
SELECT table_name.a, table_name.b, table_name.c 
FROM table_name 
WHERE table_name.dist_ft<3001
AND table_name.ID>=m
AND table_name.ID<=n
;
```

Updated with more general case based on comments-

```
Select table_name.a, table_name.b, table_name.c from tablename 
where tablename.id in 
(select top n tablename.id from tablename) 
and tablename.id not in 
(select top m tablename.id from tablenane)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. "ID" is a field in table_name i.e. it is not the row number. Is there a system field that may be the row number otherwise?

I understood your suggestion at the latter half of your response; however, I was not able to get 
SELECT TOP 16 table_name.a, table_name.b, table_name.c 
...
to work! It seemed like having a, b, c, etc. was throwing off TOP. The TOP examples I kept seeing on other forums just had one e.g. table_name.a. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry was rushed at the end earlier. Select a,b,c from tablename where id in (select top n id from tablename) and id not in (select top m from tablenane)

Answer (score 0):

Records m to n are the records 1 to n minus the records 1 to m-1. Be aware though that you need an `ORDER BY` clause for a `TOP` clause to make sense.

Here is an example with m = 31 to n = 40 and an order by all three selected columns. MS Access does not support `EXCEPT` so we cannot subtract the two data sets, which would be the straight-forward way to go. We could also express the desired result as the top n where (a,b,c) not in top m-1, but MS Access does not support an `IN` clause on multiple columns either. So I am using an anti join here (for which I select `dist_ft`, but it can be any non-nullable column of the table).

In case your table has a unique ID column, you can use a more readable `where (id) not in (select top 30 id ...)` instead of an anti join. In any way make sure to apply the same `WHERE` clause (`dist_ft < 3001` in your case) and `ORDER BY` clause (e.g. `ORDER BY a, b, c`) to the main query and subquery.

```
SELECT TOP 40 a, b, c
FROM table_name t
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT TOP 30 a, b, c, dist_ft
  FROM table_name
  WHERE dist_ft < 3001
  ORDER BY a, b, c
) no ON no.a = t.a AND no.b = t.b AND no.c = t.c
WHERE t.dist_ft < 3001
AND no.dist_ft is null
ORDER BY t.a, t.b, t.c;
```

MS Access is known for requiring additional parentheses on multiple joins. I cannot say whether above query works straight away or if parantheses must be added somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You sort thrice to get the result you are after. Let's say we want rows 31 to 40:

1. Sort and get top 40
2. sort in reverse order and get top 10
3. sort again to get the order you actually want

The query:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM
  SELECT TOP 10 a, b, c
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP 40 a, b, c
    FROM table_name
    WHERE t.dist_ft < 3001
    ORDER BY a, b, c
  ) top_n
  ORDER BY a desc, b desc, c desc
) top_m_to_n
ORDER BY a, b, c;
```